# I have some values in comma separated in 4 different columns

Tags: php

i have values like this :-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Courses      |       Eligibility       |   Duration      |      Fee


BCA,BBA,MBA      10+2,10+2,Graduation      3Y,3Y,2Y         1Lak,1Lak,2Lak
```

and Now I want like :-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Courses      |       Eligibility       |   Duration      |      Fee

BCA                     10+2                  3Y                1Lak

BBA                     10+2                  3Y                1Lak

MBA                   Graduation              2Y                2Lak



Note:-  

  <?php $course='BCA,BBA,MBA'; 
        $eligibility='BCA,BBA,MBA';
        $duration='10+2,10+2,Graduation';         
        $fee='1Lak,1Lak,2Lak'; 

   ?>
```

I don't know how to solve this prob please help me . thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to fix this unnormalized data? Or simply want to retain a badly structured database table, but display it cleanly?

Comment: Could you change the structure of your data? you could use an array of your courses, each item of it contains its own information in another array, like this

$course[] = [ 'eligibility' => 'BCA' , 'duration' => '10+2','fee'=>'1LAK'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply use `explode` with `forearch` function.

```
$tag1=$data['courses_fee'];
$tags = explode(',', $tag1);
foreach($tags as $vals)
{                                                      
echo $vals."\n"; 
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at `explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$course = "BCA,BBA,MBA";
$course = explode(",",$course);
//$course is now an array of "BCA", "BBA", "MBA"
```